Is the order of body of HTTP request guaranteed
The body of HTTP request could be many kinds of types, such as JSON, protobuf etc.
I want to know if the order of body is guaranteed.
For example, if the client sends a JSON {"a": 1, "b": 2} throught HTTP body, could the server receive the JSON with another order: {"b": 2, "a": 1}.
Same question on protobuf.
I've tried with Postman and a Python HTTP server, it seems that the order is guaranteed but I don't know if there is some exception. I need to know this because I want to make client calculate the MD5 of HTTP request body to do some check at the server side. If the order is not guaranteed, the MD5 is obviously not reliable.

From whom are you seeking this guarantee? Your HTTP-client library can probably make that guarantee - provided you don't have any client-side middlewares that could rewrite the request-body. As for JSON serializers, that's really up to them...
